# While rebooting the remote server its reboot the ansible server itself while executing below playbook

Tags: ssh, ansible, ansible-inventory, checkpoint

---

- name: reboot
  hosts: checkpoint
  tasks:

  - name: reboot checkpoint
    command: reboot
    register: save_uptime
  - debug:
     msg: "reboot done"

it shows as "remote side unexpectedly closed network connection" it rebooted ansible server not my target server.how to resolve

Comment: Hi. Can you please edit your question and format your code correctly ? There are formating aids to the right of the edit screen.

Answer (score 1):

Since command module runs specified command on all selected remote hosts (https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/command_module.html), I'd suspect that hosts file might be an issue in your case.

Also, you can use module reboot (https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/reboot_module.html) to perform the operation (assuming you are using Ansible 2.7+)

Comment: I am using ansible 2.7 in that also I have used the reboot module while running that playbook it shows the error as " FAILED! => {"changed": false, "elapsed": 0, "msg": "Running reboot with local connection would reboot the control node.", "rebooted": false}
"

Comment: Well, error message says that you are trying to reboot the machine with ansible, (as expected), so I would check the hosts file. Most likely the error is here. Check the warnings during the use of playbook, sometimes there is an error like this: `[WARNING]: Unable to parse /path/to/hosts/file as an inventory source`. After that usually you can see `[WARNING]: provided hosts list is empty, only localhost is available. Note that the implicit localhost does not match 'all'`. If this is your case, then hosts file is the issue

Comment: in my host file I am given the server details as ansible_connection=local and ansible_username and ansible_password, if i removed that ansible_connection it shows the error as " UNREACHABLE! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Authentication or permission failure. In some cases, you may have been able to authenticate and did not have permissions on the target directory. Consider changing the remote tmp path in ansible.cfg to a path rooted in \"/tmp\". "  while giving ansible_connection= ssh also it shows the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar problem trying to use the built-in Reboot Ansible module on a Dell Enterprise SONiC switch (actually a virtual switch in GNS3).  When I tried to reboot the switch from my Ansible control-node VM, the VM rebooted without giving me a warning.

The Answer turned out to be that the Ansible-Galaxy collection I am using to manage the switches uses either the 'connection: network_cli' or 'connection: httpapi' to the switch.  The rest of the Play I was running did indeed use those, but I needed to specify 'connection: ssh' for the task that would reboot the switch.

The reason the built-in Ansible module was rebooting my control-node was that the connection methods I had specified weren't valid for that module, so it fell back to targeting the local-host.  I found that out by running my playbook with the '--check' and '-vvvvv' options to see what would be done by the playbook in detail, without actually applying the changes.

I suspect that OP had the same problem because their host had 'checkpoint' in the name, and when I looked at the Checkpoint firewall Ansible-Galaxy collections they also use 'connection: httpapi" instead of the default ssh.

As an aside, I also needed to specify where to find the reboot command on my Dell Enterprise SONiC switch OS.  When I didn't specify where to find the command on the switch, the switch would still reboot but because the module caused a kernel dump on it.

After all that I can now reliably reboot the switch with the built-in Ansible module.  Here is my working (on current software as of September 6, 2023) task to reboot my switch:

```
 - name: Reboot Switch with ansible reboot
    connection: ssh
    become: true
    ansible.builtin.reboot:
      reboot_command: '/usr/local/bin/reboot'
      msg: 'Reboot initiated by Ansible'
      connect_timeout: 5
      reboot_timeout: 300
      pre_reboot_delay: 3
      post_reboot_delay: 45
      test_command: whoami
```

p.s. The rest of the module options used mean:

```
msg: -Broadcast this message to logged in admins
connect_timeout: -Close the SSH session after 5 seconds instead of waiting for normal SSH timeout
reboot_timeout: -Give up on waiting for the reboot after 300 seconds
pre_reboot_delay: -Wait 3 seconds after logging in before rebooting
post_reboot_delay: -Wait 45 seconds after reboot command before trying ssh again.  Keep trying until 'reboot_timeout' value
test_command: -After reboot and logging back in with ssh, type the command 'whoami' and wait for some response to make sure the host is back online.
```